# How to do mutex lock with a conditional variable in while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, c++17, mutex

I have two functions where one is to run serveRunForever and another is shutDown.

```
Server::runForever ()
{
while(!doStop_)
{
unique_lock<mutex> lck(stop);
//Do something, it should be looping in while loop
CV.wait(lck, [this]() {return doStop_;});
}
```

The above is not looping it start waiting in CV.wait().

```
Server::shutDown()
{
scoped_lock lck(stop);
doStop_ = true;
CV.notify_one();
}
```

the runForever is not looping in while, I would like to be in loop continuously untill shutdown called. Help me with this. I would really appreciate any leads and suggestions to this.

Comment: remove this `scoped_lock ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1**

I did modifications to your program so that it works now. Mainly I had to make `doStop_ = true;` instead of `doStop_ = false;`, because according to logic of English program should stop when do-stop becomes true.

Also you have to place mutex guards the way I showed in my code below, i.e. first lock is outside while loop, and second flag-setting lock should be scoped outside notify call. In fact you actually don't need while loop if you use `wait` with predicate, as said in [std docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).

Here is simulation of working process:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/Eh1899EG5)

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

class Server {
public:
    void runForever();
    void shutDown();
private:
    std::condition_variable CV;
    std::mutex stop;
    bool doStop_ = false;
};

void Server::runForever() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(stop);
    while (!doStop_)
        CV.wait(lck, [this]() { return doStop_; });
}

void Server::shutDown() {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(stop);
        doStop_ = true;
    }
    CV.notify_one();
}

int main() {
    auto const time_begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto TimeElapsed = [&]{
        return double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - time_begin).count()) / 1000;
    };

    Server server;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::thread t0([&]{
        std::cout << "Server started at " << TimeElapsed() << " sec" << std::endl;
        server.runForever();
        std::cout << "Server stopped at " << TimeElapsed() << " sec" << std::endl;
    });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1500));
    server.shutDown();
    t0.join();
}
```

Output:

```
Server started at 0.2 sec
Server stopped at 1.7 sec
```

---

**Part 2**

If you need to do some computations inside while loop, not just wait, then conditional variable is not for you. You should use [std::atomic bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/atomic) instead, or just regular bool is almost enough too. Atomic allows for changed value of bool variable to be propagated immediately. See code below:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/Ejv5ddjY9)

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

class Server {
public:
    void runForever();
    void shutDown();
private:
    std::atomic<bool> doStop_ = false;
};

void Server::runForever() {
    while (!doStop_) {
        std::cout << "Doing computation..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    }
}

void Server::shutDown() {
    doStop_ = true;
}

int main() {
    auto const time_begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto TimeElapsed = [&]{
        return double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - time_begin).count()) / 1000;
    };

    Server server;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::thread t0([&]{
        std::cout << "Server started at " << TimeElapsed() << " sec" << std::endl;
        server.runForever();
        std::cout << "Server stopped at " << TimeElapsed() << " sec" << std::endl;
    });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(900));
    server.shutDown();
    t0.join();
}
```

Output:

```
Server started at 0.21 sec
Doing computation...
Doing computation...
Doing computation...
Doing computation...
Doing computation...
Server stopped at 1.21 sec
```

---

**Part 3**

Also together with atomic bool you can use condition variable inside while loop to use it for pausing purpose instead of `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`.

Condition variable will help on the very last iteration before stop, will help to terminate early before whole pause has finished.

You can see in the example below in console output that server has stopped early at `1.1 sec` compared to `1.2 sec` in the example of **Part 2** of my answer.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/85jqj7191)

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

class Server {
public:
    void runForever();
    void shutDown();
private:
    std::atomic<bool> doStop_ = false;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable CV;
};

void Server::runForever() {
    while (!doStop_) {
        std::cout << "Doing computation..." << std::endl;
        
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex_);
        CV.wait_for(lck, std::chrono::milliseconds(200),
            [this]{ return bool(doStop_); });
    }
}

void Server::shutDown() {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mutex_);
        doStop_ = true;
    }
    CV.notify_all();
}

int main() {
    auto const time_begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto TimeElapsed = [&]{
        return double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - time_begin).count()) / 1000;
    };

    Server server;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::thread t0([&]{
        std::cout << "Server started at " << TimeElapsed() << " sec" << std::endl;
        server.runForever();
        std::cout << "Server stopped at " << TimeElapsed() << " sec" << std::endl;
    });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(900));
    server.shutDown();
    t0.join();
}
```

Output:

```
Server started at 0.203 sec
Doing computation...
Doing computation...
Doing computation...
Doing computation...
Doing computation...
Server stopped at 1.1 sec
```

Comment: Hello Arty, it will not loop over inside while loop, it just wait till the shutdown is called. I need to loop continuously over while loop.

Comment: @NikhilGowdaShivaswmay Probably, I didn't understand your question fully. Run my code, there is `Try it online!` link there. Isn't it doing what you need? I.e. waits in runForever until shutDown is called. Do you need to do some computations inside this loop? Then conditional variable is not what you need. Please tell me more details about your task and I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Please see this ```void Server::runForever() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(stop);
    while (!doStop_){ std::court<<"Looping..."<<std::endl; //it should print continuously till shutdown call.
        CV.wait(lck, [this]() { return doStop_; });
}}```

Comment: @NikhilGowdaShivaswmay Understood what you want, I'll correct my answer in 2-3 minutes. And notify you.

Comment: @NikhilGowdaShivaswmay I just updated my answer, added **Part 2** which says what to do if you need not just to wait inside while loop, but to do some useful work. Please read it. You don't need conditional variable in such case, but atomic bool.

Comment: Thanks it really works with ```std::atomic```. I would like to know what's wrong if I use wait_until instead of this_thread::sleep_for. For example try this with ```void Server::runForever() {     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(stop);     while (!doStop_){ std::court<<"Looping..."<<std::endl; /*it should print continuously till shutdown call.         */auto now = std::chrono:: system_clock::now(); CV.wait_until(lck, now+std::chrono:: milliseconds (200), [this]() { return doStop_; }); }}``` I am asking this out of curiosity.

Comment: @NikhilGowdaShivaswmay Just added **Part 3** of my answer explaining how to use condition variable to replace `this_thread::sleep_for()`. Please put a look!